# Barcode file reading c++

Tags: c++, vector, barcode

forum. I've been a bit stuck for a few days in a lab that i was assigned last week. it's supposed to be a lab where we are to write a code for a program that acts as a POS (point of sale) system allowing the user to put items in a cart and at checkout display each item ordered, price, quantity and a total.

Here is the a more detailed list of requirements for the assignment so you can get the whole picture:

1. NO GLOBAL VARIABLES OR GLOBAL CONSTANTS ARE ALLOWED IN THIS LAB, EXCEPT FOR FILE NAME.
2. Your program MUST read the inventory data stored in the file LabData.txt and load the data into 4 separate vectors:

   - a. 1 vector for the barcodes
   - b. 1 vector for the product description
   - c. 1 vector for the quantity available (inventory)
   - d. 1 vector for the unit price (must contain prices with 2 decimal
     places as read from the file)   NOT USING VECTORS WILL EARN YOU A ZERO
     FOR THIS LAB.   These are parallel vectors.
3. The data file that was provided currently has 4 items. The file format is:   bar code, item description, inventory quantity, and 
   unit price   You must add 2 more items to the file you will use. Use
   real items found in your household in order to store real barcodes and
   product names. You can determine the price and the quantity available.
   When creating your data, use this website to test that you have valid
   bar codes: http://www.searchupc.com      Your file must have 6 items.
   However keep in mind that your program will be tested with files than
   can have less or more items, hence DO NOT LIMIT your program to a
   specific number of items.
4. Create a function named ReadDataFile, which reads the data from the file
   and stores the data in the vectors. The data file must be read from
   `C:\temp\`. You may specify the prototype for this function in whatever way
   makes sense to you, but it must take a least two arguments. This function
   should be called from main to load the data into the vectors.
5. In main, prompt the user for the bar code (or name) of the item s/he wants
   to purchase (determine a user-friendly prompt). You must have only one cin
   for this and your program must know whether a bar code or an item name was
   entered and operate accordingly. It is highly recommended (however not
   required) that you write separate functions to handle some of the following
   scenarios:

   - a.  If the item is not in the list of items, display an error message and
     allow the user to continue shopping.
   - b.  In the cases where the desired item is in the list, prompt for how
     many the user wants to buy and validate that you have enough units in
     inventory to sell, otherwise display an appropriate error message.
   - c.  When enough inventory units are available, reduce the quantity
     purchased from the quantity available in your vector and add the bar code
     of the item and quantity purchased to the shopping cart. You may use any
     data structure you wish to store the shopping cart data. Keep in mind
     that the shopping cart will be printed to the screen when the program
     finishes and that there is not a fixed number of items that the user can
     purchase.
   - d.  A user might want to purchase more units of an item s/he has already
     purchased (is already in the shopping cart). In this case, your program
     should update the quantity in the shopping cart and in the inventory
     vector accordingly.
   - e.  Allow the user to continue purchasing items until s/he enters `9999`
     as a bar code/item name.  `9999` is the sentinel for checkout. When this
     happens, display the items stored in the shopping cart:

     - i.   Barcode
     - ii.  Product description
     - iii. Quantity
     - iv.  Item total (quantity * price)   This output MUST be produced by
           calling a separate function. You can decide on the function
           name, prototype, format of the output, etc. It must take at
           least one argument.
6. After the user checkouts the shopping cart, display a grand total in main.
   You might choose the format and proper user-friendly message.
7. Document all of your functions
8. Not closing the file

That is the assignments requirements.

Now, i got as far as making the vectors for the program, but I'm having a problem understanding how to get the vectors to read the text file and use the text file's content to get the user's inputted item accurately.

here is my code so far

```
void ReadDataFile(vector<string>&, vector <double>&, vector <int>&, vector <string>&);
int main()
{
vector<string>bar_code;
vector<double>unit_price;
vector<int>inventory_quantity;
vector<string>item_description;

ReadDataFile(bar_code, unit_price, inventory_quantity, item_description);
system("Pause");
return 0;}

void ReadDataFile(vector<string>&bar_code, vector <double>& unit_price,
vector <int>& inventory_quantity, vector <string>& item_description)
{
string Bar_code;
int Unit_price;
double Inventory_quantity;
string Item_description;

ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("C:\\Temp\\data.txt");
while (!inputfile.eof())
{
    inputfile >> Bar_code;
    bar_code.push_back(Bar_code);

    inputfile >> Unit_price;
    unit_price.push_back(Unit_price);

    inputfile >> Inventory_quantity;
    inventory_quantity.push_back(Inventory_quantity);

    inputfile >> Item_description;
    item_description.push_back(Item_description);


}
}
```

also here is the text file that was provided with the first four items needed to be read:

> 367730154604 Pringles 20 1.50
>
> 0164000031190 Sour 10 2.50
>
> 391360056850 Onion 35 2.97
>
> 040255682427 Potato 23 2.98

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: To start with, all four items om a single line are related, they are a single *record*. In C++ that usually corresponds to a `class` or `struct`. Using a structure to collect the members of the record will allow you to only have *one* vector, which may make things easier for you.

Comment: More related to your problem, what *is* your problem? Besides that you should not do `while (!inputfile.eof())` (do some searching and you will find many explanations of why), the file-reading function should work fine. Can you please elaborate on what the problem you're having is? And remember that stackoverflow.com is not a "give me code" or "coder for hire" site, you need to show us what you have tried, and tell us specifically what the problem is with your existing code.

Comment: Actually formatting the text of your assignment I read it... This assignment makes me sad. You should fire your uni/professor for that... :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your data structures around so it's not unnecessarily clumsy and error prone. This is 2015:

Use a struct:

```
struct Record {
    string bar_code;
    double unit_price;
    int inventory_quantity;
    string item_description;
};

vector<Record> ReadDataFile();
```

Next, implement stream extraction by reading all lines (`getline`) and extracting the individual fields using `istringstream`.

Don't ever use `while (!s.eof())`.

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c37f81ac7478fa5c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Record {
    string bar_code;
    double unit_price;
    int inventory_quantity;
    string item_description;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Record const&);
};

vector<Record> ReadDataFile();

int main() {
    auto data = ReadDataFile(); 

    copy(data.begin(), data.end(), ostream_iterator<Record>(std::cout, "\n"));
}

vector<Record> ReadDataFile() {
    vector<Record> data;

    ifstream inputfile("C:\\Temp\\data.txt");

    size_t linenumber = 0;
    string line;
    while (getline(inputfile, line)) {
        linenumber += 1;

        Record r;
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (iss >> r.bar_code >> r.item_description >> r.inventory_quantity >> r.unit_price)
            data.push_back(r);
        else
            throw runtime_error("Parse error in line #" + to_string(linenumber) + " '" + line + "'");
    }

    return data;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Record const& r) {
    return os << r.bar_code << " " << r.item_description << " " << r.inventory_quantity << " " << r.unit_price;
}
```

Prints the input back to the output.

Comment: Finally completed the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c37f81ac7478fa5c)

Comment: I realize after formatting the question that your assignment imposes ridiculous requirements ... I'm sorry for that. I hope this answer shows you that code does **not** have to be as bad as it was taught in your class. If that is of any consolation.

Comment: hi i am still learning c++ this my first computer language class that i am taking i just having the problem with number five how should i put in the mean. if u can help me with that thank you